# Unable to publish Android project from Smartface.io

Tags: smartface.io

I am using Publishing Wizard from Smartface to publish an Android project.
License is real, not demo
In the final step I get an error: "Error on publish" along with some hits like:
check java is 1.7 (correct!)
check path to Android SDK in Project Details (correct!)

What else should I try to make Publishing Wizard work?

Answer (score 0):

This error might occur if you have both JDK1.7 and JDK1.8 than it links to JDK1.8.

Check 1.apk in the path `C:\Users\<Your_User>\apktool\framework\`. If it exists remove it and try again. It should work.

Comment: There is no such catalog on my system. Does it mean anything? There is no 1.apk on my system anywhere.

Comment: SOLVED! In project details there was wrong path to Java: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76' instead of 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76\bin" and Smarftface wrongly indicated that it found and verified Java. Smartface was wrong because it found java files in other path: Windows\System32 and 'thought' it found them in the indicated path in Project Details.